# Porting RTOS from existing processor to a new processor

Tags: porting, rtos

Could somebody suggest the procedure to port the RTOS in existing processor to a new processor.

I'm stuck at the beginning, looking for  some help from the beginning.

Comment: You should determine your RTOS. There are a wide range of them currently. However, it's better to follow the "Porting Guide" which is provided for each one on their website.

Comment: e.g. https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-porting-guide.html

Comment: "_the_ RTOS"?  What RTOS - there is more than one.  If it is portable, the steps necessary to implement a port will be provided in the documentation.  It is not in any case usually a matter of porting it from one processor to another, but rather taking the portable part and implementing the processor specific part.  If your RTOS is not implemented in that manner, you might better pick one that is.  It is highly unlikely that you have a processor architecture for which a port of at least one RTOS does not already exist.

Comment: Often it is more a matter of providing _board-support_ for the specifics of your board design.  Being "just at the beginning" suggests that you have at least a hardware platform, and an RTOS in mind.  If not then clearly those are essential decisions and you have not even begun.  Do not mistag your questions with irrelevant tags.

Comment: On SO in general being "stuck at the beginning" is not an acceptable question.  You need to make a start and ask specific questions about problems you have encountered.  Otherwise it is just too broad and general to provide a useful answer.